# Server can't determine the length of this raw HTTP message

Tags: php, http, post, chunked-encoding

I'm attempting to stream chunked POST data using sockets in PHP to a local server for testing. This works fine if I don't chunk the request entity body and provide a Content-Length header.

However, when I chunk the transfer as follows the server doesn't recognize the end of the message. What is wrong with the raw message below that is preventing the server from correctly recognizing that the message is complete?

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
HOST: localhost
CONTENT-TYPE: text/plain
USER-AGENT: testing
ACCEPT-ENCODING: gzip,deflate,identity
TRANSFER-ENCODING: chunked

36
When in the chronicle of wasted time
0
```

After last '0' there are 2x`CRLF`, so the last 5 bytes are: `0x30, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A`.

I've tried sending this request to both a local Apache server and PHP5.4's built-in testing server. Neither can determine that the request is complete and execution hangs until the socket times out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value should be in hex 36 → 24